# How not to count the objects created within a day by the same user in Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a `Product` and `User` model and I wanted to generate statistics of product view (idea is to implement view count). I have created a new model called `ProductViewed` and signal that gets fired whenever I make a `get` request to retrieve a single `Product`. I know how to get view count for each `Product`. However I wanted to make the statistics fair and I want to remove every view generated by the same user or IP address in one day.

*product viewed model*

```
class ProductViewed(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="viewed")
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{str(self.product)} viewed on {self.created_at}'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at', )
        verbose_name_plural = "ProductViewed"
```

Query that I am using is as follows:

```
ProductViewed.objects.filter(product_id=<someid>).count()
```

I want to achieve this

```
# before filtering
Pr1 viewed on 08.07.2020 by user1, Pr1 viewed on 08.07.2020 by user1, Pr1 viewed on  08.07.2020 by user2
# after filtering
Pr1 viewed on 08.07.2020 by user1, Pr1 viewed on 08.07.2020 by user2
```

**Question**: How to remove products viewed by the same user in a day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
ProductViewed.objects.filter(product_id=<someid>).values("user", "created_at__date").distinct().count()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `distinct()`. You can add existing fields into values.

```
ProductViewed.objects.filter(product_id=<someid>).values("user", "ip_address", "created_at__date").distinct().count()
```

Comment: thanks, it worked but how to improve and make it as I questioned?

Comment: You can write condition in your signal function if ip addres is there for this day then don't create view function or skip function.

Comment: but it requires to retrieving from database all the time when I create productviewed obj. It is not gonna be the good way I guess.

Comment: Thanks I have achieved it and edited your answer